# Probability of event happening in Bernoulli scheme if most likely outcome is given?

Tags: probability

n=6 Bernoulli scheme trials are made. The most likely result is 4 successes. What's the probability that were will be no successes after all trials are completed? 
Well I know that this inequality must be true $4 < 7p$ (or should it be less or equal than?). From this I get $p > \frac{4}{7} $. How should I continue? Is it even possible to get a one number answer? Or the answer is inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question had specified that the *expected* number of successes is $4$, then we would know that the probability of success on any trial is $\frac{4}{6}$.

However, the wording used is "the most likely." That could be just (very) sloppy wording. But if we are to take the wording at face value, it means there *is* a (unique) most likely number of successes, and that most likely value is $4$.

Then by using standard facts about the Binomial distribution, we find that
$$\binom{6}{3}p^3(1-p)^3\lt \binom{6}{4}p^4(1-p)^2 \lt \binom{6}{5}p^5(1-p).$$
Cancellation and a bit of algebra yields
$$\frac{4}{7}\lt p\lt \frac{5}{7}.$$